# AWS CDK - How to prevent it from creating a default target group?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

We need to create an ECS cluster with EC2, and use an existing Application Load Balancer.

After many trials and errors I managed to make it work, however it always create an extra default target group on port 80.

This is the code I have (using Java as per requirements):

```
        cluster = Cluster.Builder.create(scope, "my-ecs-cluster")
                .vpc(awsNetwork.getVpc())
                .capacity(
                    AddCapacityOptions.builder()
                        .instanceType(new InstanceType("m5n.xlarge"))
                        .minCapacity(1)
                        .maxCapacity(1)
                        .desiredCapacity(1)
                        .associatePublicIpAddress(true)
                        .vpcSubnets(
                            SubnetSelection.builder()
                                .subnetType(SubnetType.PUBLIC)
                                .availabilityZones(Arrays.asList("us-west-2a", "us-west-2c"))
                                .build()
                        )
                    .build()
                ).build();

        taskDefinition = Ec2TaskDefinition.Builder.create(scope, "my-taskDefinition")
            .executionRole(Role.fromRoleArn(scope, "my-exec-role", "role-arn..."))
            .build();

        containerDef = ContainerDefinition.Builder.create(scope, "my-ecs-container")
                .essential(true)
                .memoryLimitMiB(2048)
                .memoryReservationMiB(2048)
                .image(ContainerImage.fromEcrRepository(
                    Repository.fromRepositoryName(scope,
                        "my-ecr",
                        "my-image"
                    ),
                    "latest")
                )
                .taskDefinition(taskDefinition)
                .build();

        containerDef.addPortMappings(PortMapping.builder()
            .hostPort(0)
            .containerPort(443)
            .protocol(Protocol.TCP)
            .build());

        taskDefinition.setDefaultContainer(containerDef);

        ApplicationLoadBalancerLookupOptions balancerLookupOptions = ApplicationLoadBalancerLookupOptions.builder()
            .loadBalancerArn("arn:aws:my-alb-arn")
            .build();

        loadBalancer = ApplicationLoadBalancer.fromLookup(scope, "my-alb", balancerLookupOptions);

        balancedEc2Service = ApplicationLoadBalancedEc2Service.Builder.create(scope, "my-ec2-service")
            .cluster(cluster)
            .desiredCount(1)
            .taskDefinition(taskDefinition)
            .loadBalancer(loadBalancer)
            .cpu(1)
            .memoryLimitMiB(2048)
            .build();

        balancedEc2Service.getService().addPlacementStrategies(PlacementStrategy.spreadAcross("attribute:ecs.availability-zone", "instanceId"));

        HealthCheck healthCheck = HealthCheck.builder()
            .path("/healthCheck")
            .protocol(software.amazon.awscdk.services.elasticloadbalancingv2.Protocol.HTTPS)
            .port("traffic-port")
            .unhealthyThresholdCount(2)
            .interval(Duration.seconds(30))
            .healthyThresholdCount(5)
            .timeout(Duration.seconds(5))
            .build();

        balancedEc2Service.getTargetGroup().setHealthCheck(healthCheck);

        ListenerCertificate listenerCertificate = ListenerCertificate.fromCertificateManager(Certificate.fromCertificateArn(scope, "dis-certificate-1", "arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:245459132561:certificate/d2962594-8a40-4f36-abd4-62a6d91d0250"));

        ApplicationTargetGroup targetGroup = ApplicationTargetGroup.Builder.create(scope, "dis-receiver-targetGroup")
            .protocol(ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS)
            .port(443)
            .healthCheck(healthCheck)
            .vpc(awsNetwork.getVpc())
            .build();

        ApplicationListener.Builder.create(scope, "dis-receiver-listener")
            .loadBalancer(loadBalancer)
            .defaultTargetGroups(Collections.singletonList(targetGroup))
            .protocol(ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS)
            .port(443)
            .certificates(Collections.singletonList(listenerCertificate))
            .build();

        balancedEc2Service.getService().attachToApplicationTargetGroup(targetGroup);
```

[image]

One of the target groups is the one I created in code.
The other one is created automatically, and it points to port 80:

[image]

If instead of using `balancedEc2Service.getService().attachToApplicationTargetGroup(targetGroup);` I set it directly into the service, like:

```
        balancedEc2Service = ApplicationLoadBalancedEc2Service.Builder.create(scope, "my-ec2-service")
            .cluster(cluster)
            .desiredCount(1)
            .taskDefinition(taskDefinition)
            .loadBalancer(loadBalancer)
            .cpu(1)
            .memoryLimitMiB(2048)
// New code
            .listenerPort(443)
            .protocol(ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS)
            .certificate(myCertificate)
            .domainName(myDomainName)
            .domainZone(myDomainZone)
//
            .build();
```

It creates only one targetGroup, and it is linked to port 443 on ECS:

[image]

However the target group itself is on port 80, and so the application gets timed out:

[image]

**How can I configure a single target group using HTTPS?**